# WooCommerce Subscriptions Emails: What are the correct 'woocommerce_email_order_details' hook function arguments (to modify "renewal" emails)?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, subscription, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm having trouble tracking down the correct hook function arguments to modify/add email content for the (WooCommerce Subscriptions-specific) 'customer_renewal_invoice' and 'processing_renewal_order' email IDs within the 'woocommerce_email_order_details' hook.

I have this working (email content modification, that is) for the standard WooCommerce order emails, but according to LoicTheAztec ([Get the email id in Woocommerce emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741577/get-the-email-id-in-woocommerce-emails#comment91576428_47742782)), the Subscriptions plugin uses different hook function arguments; I just don't know what those are.

Here is a simplified version of what I have in place:

```php
add_action ('woocommerce_email_order_details', 'custom_email_notification', 5, 4);
function custom_email_notification( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    if ( 'customer_processing_order' == $email->id || 'customer_invoice' == $email->id || 'customer_on_hold_order' == $email->id || 'customer_renewal_invoice' == $email->id || 'processing_renewal_order' == $email->id ){
        echo "Extra content here";
    }
}
```

The first three "standard"/WooCommerce email IDs engage properly, but the last two (which are specific to the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin) never engage/trigger; I know this is because my hook arguments are incorrect, but I do not know how to correct them.

I feel the essence of the information I need is mentioned in these other posts, but I can't quite put all of the pieces together; listed in order of perceived relevance:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42097450

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31677646

[WooCommerce Subscription Cancellation Email to Customer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57317710)

My life in continually made easier/bearable by the incredible help from the users here on StackOverflow; thank you all for that, and thank you in advance for any help you can provide with this issue.

Comment: Sorry, left out another potentially relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51110950/11984440.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably actually want `woocommerce_subscriptions_email_order_details`, it appears to be called from both emails you want (templates/emails/customer-renewal-invoice.php and templates/emails/customer-processing-renewal-order.php). In both of those it receives `$order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email`. But if you want to handle any other cases, sometimes it's called in other places with  `$subscription, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email`.

Comment: That did the trick! Seems obvious now, but I tell you what: I sure tried to find the answer on my own beforehand. Thank you very much; things are finally working as they should!

Comment: Oh, I don't blame ya', the documentation on Subscriptions is pretty thin.